# Button repeatedly calls GET method and does not POST when editing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post

I am trying to edit an entry in my database, but when I click submit, it just keeps calling the GET method over and over again and I cannot figure out why. I have tested this through breakpoints and there is no evidence of the POST method running - is it something to do with my Manufacturer binding?

**Controller**

```
// GET: Model/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Model model = db.Models.Find(id);
        if (model == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        ViewBag.Manufacturers = GetManufacturerList(model);

        return View(model);
    }

    // POST: Model/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EditPost(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var modelToUpdate = db.Models.Find(id);
        if (TryUpdateModel(modelToUpdate, "",
           new string[] { "ModelName", "ManufacturerID" }))
        {
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (DataException /* dex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
            }
        }

        ViewBag.Manufacturers = GetManufacturerList();

        return View(modelToUpdate);
    }
```

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Model</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ModelID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModelName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ModelName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModelName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Manufacturer.ManufacturerName, "Manufacturer",
                htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-5">
                @Html.DropDownList("ManufacturerID", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Manufacturers,
                    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Manufacturer.ManufacturerName, "",
                    new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Models:**

```
public class Model
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Manufacturer")]
    [ForeignKey("Manufacturer")]
    public int ManufacturerID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ModelID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Model cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9.-/() ]+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid characters used. A-Z or a-z, 0-9, '.', '-', '()' and '/' allowed.")]
    [Display(Name = "Model")]
    public string ModelName { get; set; }

    public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Manufacturer
{
    [Required]
    public int ManufacturerID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Manufacturer cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9.-/() ]+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid characters used. A-Z or a-z, 0-9, '.', '-', '()' and '/' allowed.")]
    [Display(Name = "Manufacturer")]
    public string ManufacturerName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Model> Models { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried applying a `[HttpGet]` on top of your `Edit` method or maybe try renaming `Edit` to `GetEdit`?

Answer (score 1):

Your HttpPost method is named "EditPost".  Shouldn't it be named simply "Edit" like this?

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Model model)
{
```

Here is a tutorial that might help you:  https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view

Comment: All well and good, but it doesn't answer the question, which is why a get method that keeps firing. Any ideas?

Comment: @Gert Arnold Not 100% sure.  Would it be because he does not have any parameters when he calls  BeginForm(), and no post method called "Edit" in his controller, so it's defaulting to the get method that rendered the page?

Comment: Thanks for your input but this is incorrect. As there are two 'edit' methods with the same parameters you need to change one of the signatures to 'override' it.

Comment: Not yet, still going round in circles with it.

Comment: If you want to keep the EditPost method as it is, you could try adding parameters to your view when you call BeginForm() like this:  
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditPost", "Models", Model.ID))
{

Comment: Figured it out - I forgot to add the ActionName attribute!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - I forgot to add the ActionName attribute as below:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult EditPost(int? id)
{...}
```